# How inflation explains the missing monopole?

Tags: universe, cosmological-inflation, magnetic-monopoles

I read that Alan Guth used phase transition model of early universe to dilute the monopole so that nowadays we don't get to see any of them? I know there is no monopole in nature but I am interested to know how the inflation upset the grand symmetry?

Comment: What grand symmetry are you referring to?

Comment: @G.Smith: I think (all) grand unified theories predicted magnetic monopole, I tried to confirm this but I don't know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Inflation solve the Magnetic Monopole problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/how-does-inflation-solve-the-magnetic-monopole-problem)

Comment: @DavidH: Yes, especially the link in the comment section.