# Why monopoles of magnets do not exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

Why monopoles (in magnets) do not exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261246/2451

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is asking specifically for the possibility mm to be already inside ferromagnetic matter. That is different than in general asking why mm do not exist! The question should be re-opened and be asked to be more specific titled and described.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody know why or if they do or don't exist. They just have never been found, in spite of some fairly extensive searching.

There are some theoretical reasons to suspect they do exist. See [How does Inflation solve the Magnetic Monopole problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12484/37364)

Answer (score 1):

*"Why monopoles (**in magnets**) do not exist?"*

Are you asking why natural magnetic monopoles (mm) don't exist or never have been found inside condensed magnetized matter?

Dirac has predicted that if natural mm existed they would be in the form of vastly separated monopole and antimonopole pairs connected via an infinite thin [Dirac String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Dirac_string). So, even Dirac in his theory actually admits that these are actually dipoles with their two poles separated by a long distance.  [Gauss's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism) for magnetism, one of Maxwell's equations, is the mathematical statement that magnetic monopoles do not exist.

In that sense, synthetic mimics of Dirac magnetic monopoles have been emulated in artificial [spin ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_ice) and by other techniques and [condensed-matter systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#%22Monopoles%22_in_condensed-matter_systems) or [strongly correlated electrons materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_correlated_material) as emergent phenomena researched by various independent research groups as described in these research papers here for example:

[Physical Review](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.030401)

[Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12954)

[other related papers](https://tinyurl.com/7xkkj2t2)

The closest to your question research I could find of possible natural (not synthetic) *magnetic monopoles* existing inside ferromagnetic matter is this theoretical paper which reports also experiment results that could infer to their existence (phenomenology):

[Science](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.1089408)

[Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0310232)